# How to find the full strings in List2 by searching with the substrings in List1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists composed of amino acid sequences (this is not a biology question, but stated for context) where `List1` contains substrings (partial sequences) of full strings (complete sequences). `List2` contains full strings where some contain the substrings from `List1` and some of the strings do not.

These lists are large which is why they were made, but now I do not know how to trace the substrings to the full strings.

Below is a modified example of what the two lists look like using real data from my own data set. For the two substrings contained within `List1` there should be two matches in `List2`. I have confirmed that the matches are in `List2`.

```
List1 = ['QSLNQNVVSRTCPAVVSHRARRAVRVMATGSPLTFSKYQGLGNDFILIDNRHTSEPVVTPEQAVKICDRNFGVGGDGVIFALPPVGETDLTMRIFNSDGSEPEMCGNGIRCLAKFVADIDKSSPRKYKIHTLAGLIQPELLADGQVRVDMGAPILDGSKVPTTLTPTEGNTVVQQDLVVDGKTYKVTCVSMGNPHAVIYTCNGKTIKIDDLESDLAALGPKFERNTVFPARTNTEFVEVISPSHVRMVVWERGAGRTLACGTGACALVVAGILEGRVDRSKTCRVDLPGGPLQIEWSTVDNHIYMTGPAELVFGGSLRV', 'DMRISYERGGLEEAAFRGRDPMQVFDEWFKAAVAGKVCEEPNAISLASSNPSGQPSVRVVLLKGYDERGFVFYTNYSSRKGTELESGSAAFSIYWEKLQRQIRVEGTVEHVSEEESTAYFHSRPRGSQIGAWVSAQSQPCRNRGEMEARNAELQQRFSDESVPVPKPPHWGGYLIRPTRIEFWQGRPSRLHDRIRFRRPSPNESWVMERLQP']
List2 = [Seq('SSLPSNSVWASGKSYLGHLY*CVHPAHTVTFTLPLVAA*YRALSYDVRRSKFLT...LHL', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('PLYHLILSGPLENPT*DTYTDAFILLTRSLSPSLS*PRNTALCHMTFAVQNFLL...CIF', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('LSTI*FCLGLWKILPRTPILMRSSCSHGHFHPPSRSRVIPRFVI*RSPFKISYS...TAS', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('EDAVIESKCGQSHMPGCCQPPGTQGCARNGYGIAPDVLQVSGPW*RFHLD*QSP...VER', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('KMQSLNQNVVSRTCPAVVSHRARRAVRVMATGSPLTFSKYQGLGNDFILIDNRH...*RG', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('RCSH*IKMWSVAHARLLSATGHAGLCA*WLRDRP*RSPSIRALVTISS*LTIAT...GRE', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')) Seq('VLTHVVASDKELLARAVRWEALPSRKNLSGLHHPSAPKPLSNSQYYSKKKPIRL...DFV', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('FLHTWLLPTRSCSRVQSAGKHCQAEKTSQVCITHRRLSH*ATLNITVKKNQSVS...QTS', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('SYTRGCFRQGVARACSPLGSIAKQKKPLRSASPIGA*AIKQLSILQ*KKTNPSH...RLR', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('HEVCVSVT*QHYVLP*RTNLWGHPSSELLSRVRINC*LQLLSVLNQCSIAHHRA...CKN', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('TKSAFQ*HNNIMFFPNAQIYGDTPAPSCYHVCA*IANCNYYLCSINAV*HIIAP...CVR', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*')), Seq('RSLRFSNITTLCSSLTHKFMGTPQLRVAITCAHKLLTATIICAQSMQYSTSSRQ...V*E', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*'))]
```

Here is a highly condensed version of my script for more context:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna

path_to_allxmlfiles = "path/to/xml/file/dir/"  # Path to a directory where a bunch of XML files are found.
xml_dir = os.listdir(path_to_allxmlfiles)

path_to_transcriptome = "path/to/transcriptome/file.fasta" #This is just a giant fasta file.
transcriptomefile = open(path_to_transcriptome, 'r')

List1=[]
for file in xml_dir:
    if file.endswith(".xml"):
        xml_file_path = os.path.join(path_to_allxmlfiles, file)
        xml_files = open(xml_file_path, 'r')
            for lines in xml_files:
                tree = ET.parse(xml_files)
                root = tree.getroot()

                for substring in root.findall("./BlastOutput_iterations/Iteration/Iteration_hits/Hit[1]/Hit_hsps/Hsp[1]/substring"):
                    SUBSTRING = substring.text
                    List1.append(SUBSTRING)
fullstrlist1 = []
fullstrlist2 = []
fullstrlist3 = []
fullstrlist4 = []
fullstrlist5 = []
fullstrlist6 = []
for line in transcriptomefile:
    if (stuff_was_done_here):

      A_lot_of_stuff_done_here_where_I_appended_full_strings_to_six_lists. # I am translating in 6 reading frames so this is necessary because each reading frame is unique.

        List2 = [fullstrlist1, fullstrlist2, fullstrlist3, fullstrlist4, fullstrlist5, fullstrlist6] #List2 is a combination of the six lists above.

for item in List2:
    if any(x in item for x in List1):
        print(item)
```

What is given back in `print(item)` are not the items that contain the substrings from `List1` from what I can tell.

This is my first question on StackOverflow. Please let me know if any more detail is needed. I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: BTW the line `for line in xml_files:` is a mistake. You're already in a loop of each XML file, and you want to read the entire XML file ( as you have done  with `tree = ET.parse(xml_files)`, except you appear to be repeating this operation for EVERY SINGLE LINE of every XML file.
Unless I am mistaken, and each line of each your files is a complete single line XML document?... that code still wouldn't work , in that case.

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen. I just used the placeholder name of `List2` to keep everything simple. In my actual script, `List2` has a descriptive name.

Comment: Thank you @Zv_oDD. I appreciate you pointing that out about the  `for lines in xml_files:`. The script runs fine the way it is written out on my end, but I will go back and make some changes to see if I'm being to wordy in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your asking, but here is a sample of 2 search methods...

```py
#Sub Strings
List1 = ["Apple", "Mulberry"]

# List of lists
List2 = [
    ["Apple", "Grapefruit", "Guava"],
    ["Banana", "Blueberry", "Grape"],
    ["Lemon", "Lime"],
    ["Loquat", "Lychee", "Mango"],
    ["Mulberry", "Nectarine", "Strawberry"],
    ["Pomegranate", "Raspberry"]
]

#a substring to search for.
List3 = ["berry", "ime"]

print("Search for whole matching strings", List1)
for item in List2:
    if any(x in item for x in List1):
        print(item)

print('\n Substring search for substrings', List3)
for group in List2:
    for item in group:
        if any(sbs in item for sbs in List3):
            print(group)
            break # no need to keep searching the group
```

and the output

```
Search for whole matching strings ['Apple', 'Mulberry']
['Apple', 'Grapefruit', 'Guava']
['Mulberry', 'Nectarine', 'Strawberry']

 Substring search for substrings ['berry', 'ime']
['Banana', 'Blueberry', 'Grape']
['Lemon', 'Lime']
['Mulberry', 'Nectarine', 'Strawberry']
['Pomegranate', 'Raspberry']
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to know! Thank you so much! During the `print('\n Substring search for substrings', List3)` section instead of `print(group)` I just needed to `print(item)`. I'm trying to capture the entire sequence, and your solution allows me to do that.